# Append a parameter to the end of a URL with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am struggling to do something which appears quite simple...

I use PHP cURL to scrape data and insert it into my website. cURL saves the data as a string in `$data` before it is output.

What I am trying to do is target all of the URL's contained within `$data`. The URL's sometimes contain a fixed value parameter that I need move to the end of the URL. The URL's look like this, where `category=widgets` can appear anywhere in the URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/script.php?category=widgets&show=all&size=big
```

I need to move the parameter `category=widgets` to the end of all URL's, so they look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/script.php?show=all&size=big&category=widgets
```

I'm thinking that I can firstly remove all occurences of `category=widgets` with str_replace, that's the easy bit.

The problem I have is appending `category=widgets` to the end of the URL. Because the URL is dynamic, perhaps preg_replace is more appropriate. I'm new to regular expressions, and it's giving me a headache.

Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Question: Why do you need to move the parameter to the end?

Comment: Indeed; there's no reason why `http://www.mysite.com/script.php?show=all&size=big&category=widgets` should behave any differently from `http://www.mysite.com/script.php?category=widgets&show=all&size=big`. Where does this need to have the parameters in a certain order come from?

Comment: @Felix Kling @Matt Gibson Yes the script still works regardless of the parameter order. However, I need to consolidate the URL structure across the site, we have URL's with many of the same parameters but in a different order. We loose bandwidth when the site is crawled 100 different times to what is essentially the same content but with a different URL. There are also SEO benefits to consolidating URL structures, with the flow of page rank.

Comment: Guys, to clarify, I need a quick and dirty solution for the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend making use of the [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url), as this is liable to be considerably more robust in the long term than string manipulation.

As such, you could use parse_url to extract the various chunks and then assemble a new URL based on these as required.

Comment: You could then use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/parse_str) to parse the query part (make sure to use the array argument) and [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) to reassemble it.